# How to comment and like an Instagram post using c#

Tags: c#, .net, instagram

I have an Instagram class defined like this (I got this code and I need to implement some new things):

```
class Instagram
    {
        public HttpManager http = new HttpManager();

        public bool login(string username, string password)
        {
            string source = http.getResponse("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login");

            var csrfmiddlewaretoken = http.ParseBetween(source, "\"csrfmiddlewaretoken\" value=\"", "\"");

            var values = new NameValueCollection();
            values.Add("username", username);
            values.Add("password", password);
            values.Add("csrfmiddlewaretoken", csrfmiddlewaretoken);

            http.Referer = "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login";
            source = http.getResponse("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login", values);

            return source.Contains("\"" + username + "\"");
        }

        public List<KeyValuePair<string, string> > getLatestImages(string tag)
        {
            string source = http.getResponse("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/" + tag + "/");

            var json = http.ParseBetween(source, "window._sharedData = ", ";</script>");

            dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(json);
            obj = obj.entry_data.TagPage[0].graphql.hashtag.edge_hashtag_to_media.edges;

            var returnList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

            foreach (var post in obj)
            {
                string imageurl = post.node.thumbnail_resources[1].src; // post.node.display_url;
                string posturl = "https://www.instagram.com/p/" + post.node.shortcode;
                returnList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(imageurl, posturl));
            }

            return returnList;
        }
    }
```

I get a specific set of posts which have a specific hashtag.

```
var insta = new Instagram();
insta.login("myusername", "mypassword");

Task.Run(() =>
{
    var res = insta.getLatestImages("myhashtag"); 

    foreach (var s in res)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s.Key + " WITH myhashtag");
    }
});
```

Before my question(headline question), I need to say that I read the Instagram API and wrapper InstaSharp. There is a difference between this solution(where I need to implement new things instead of making it from scratch following IAPI and IS) and examples(IAPI and IS). For example... Using InstaSharp, it is easy to like a post(but I can't use it):

```
/// <summary>
        /// Set a like on this media by the currently authenticated user.
        /// <para>Requires Authentication: False</para>
        /// <para>
        /// <c>Required Scope: </c>likes
        /// </para>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="mediaId">The id of the media to create a like for.</param>
        /// <returns>LikesResponse</returns>
        public Task<LikesResponse> Post(string mediaId)
        {
            AssertIsAuthenticated();

            var request = Request("{id}/likes", HttpMethod.Post);
            request.AddUrlSegment("id", mediaId);
            return Client.ExecuteAsync<LikesResponse>(request);
        }
```

I am also updating a class file([HttpManager](https://ufile.io/x6c75)). Any answer or hint is more than welcome. Finally, one more time, I need to make a solution according to existing code.

Answer (score 4):

No need to implement these option by yourself.
There are many open source libraries for instagram.

[InstagramApiSharp](https://github.com/ramtinak/InstagramApiSharp) is one of theme.

Send comment media:

```
var commentResponse = await InstaApi.CommentProcessor.CommentMediaAsync("MEDIA ID", "Hey Keep it up!");
```

Like media:

```
var likeResponse = await InstaApi.MediaProcessor.LikeMediaAsync("MEDIA ID");
```